# Delay A pipeline For 24Hours

Tags: azure, azure-devops, devops

Hello Im using Azure piplines for some tasks

Here is a simiple example of what im trying to achieve :

[image]

what im trying to do is to to trigger pipline2 after pipeline1 complition (this is done)
and once the pipeline 2 is triggered i want it to wait for 24 Hours before it runs
i don't know if that is possible

i tried the delay task
but it timesout in 1 Hour

i've Read that timouts are

- For 360 minutes (6 hours) on Microsoft-hosted agents with a public project and public repository
- For 60 minutes on Microsoft-hosted agents with a private project or private repository

so the option to have a task last for 24hours is only possible on self-hosted agents

i have also seen the schedule option wich is on the repo level not pipeline compeletion

i hope someone can guide me to the right direction

Answer (score 0):

Such tasks could be run with Agentless jobs: [Agentless jobs supported tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/phases?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#agentless-tasks)

```
jobs:
- job: string
  pool: server # note: the value 'server' is a reserved keyword which indicates this is an agentless job
  steps:
  - task: Delay@1
    inputs:
      delayForMinutes: '1440'
```